# Function is bounded from below if sum of partial derivatives is positive

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Let $f:\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}$ be differentiable, $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(y)\geq 0$ for all $y=(y_1,...,y_n)\in \mathbf{R}^n$. How do I show that $f$ is bounded from below by $f(0)$?

Comment: there is something missing in this question please complete it before it get close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The expression from your question is the derivative of f with respect to the radius squared. So if that is positive, then...

Answer (score 3):

Isn't 
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (x_1,x_2) \mapsto x_1 + x_2
$$
a counterexample?

Comment: Yes it is, but just because I made a mistake typing the question, it doesn't work for the correct formulation